# Can we use redux-batch-middleware with redux-observable?

Tags: redux-observable

```
const fetchListEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$.ofType('LOAD_LIST')
    .switchMap(() =>
      concat$(
        of$(openLoader()),
        fromPromise$(fetchListFromServer())
          .flatMap(list => of$(loadListSucceeded(list), closeLoader()))
          .catch(e =>
            of$(
              openSnackbar('ERROR'),
              closeLoader(),
            ),
        ),
     )
  );
```

Here `loadListSucceeded` and `closeLoader` actions will be dispatched one by one which will result in multiple re-rendering of components.

Is it also possible with redus-observable to batch multiple actions?

---

**UPDATE:**

Can we use https://github.com/mrydengren/redux-batch-middleware? The redux-batch-middleware expects array of actions but redux-observable works only for objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redux-batched-actions works well with redux-observable. Here's a demo, where you can see in the console that it only rerenders once despite there being `PONG` and `SECOND_PONG` sequentially:

https://jsbin.com/kewomex/edit?js,console,output

---

#### Edit, based on your edits and comments:

> Can we use https://github.com/mrydengren/redux-batch-middleware? The redux-batch-middleware expects array of actions but redux-observable works only for objects.

Yep! In fact, you can use [nearly] any middleware with redux-observable. redux-observable itself doesn't know anything about the things your epics dispatch. It just does:

```
rootEpic(action$, store).subscribe(store.dispatch)
```

Armed that knowledge, you next need to be mindful that middleware is applied in the order provided to `applyMiddleware` from left to right. You can think of it as `store.dispatch` passes whatever was dispatched to the first middleware, which then chooses to do something and/or then pass that action along to the next middleware, etc.

So while redux-observable itself doesn't care what actions look like, your epics probably do. e.g. the `ofType` operator does. This might not cause any issues since if the "action" that was dispatched is actually an array of actions, `action.type` will just be `undefined` and be filtered out by `ofType` without errors. Regardless, probably a good idea to put redux-batch-middleware before redux-observable so the arrays are consumed and each inside action emitted before being given back to your epics. This also means that each of those actions could also be handled by other epics too, which is awesome.

https://jsbin.com/yemixet/edit?js,console,output

```
import { batch, batching } from 'redux-batch-middleware';

const store = createStore(batching(rootReducer),
  applyMiddleware(batch, epicMiddleware)
);
```

Comment: sorry I am using https://github.com/mrydengren/redux-batch-middleware instead of redux-batch-actions. I have updated the question. Thanks for your help.